# Client is not receiving Object sent by Server over ObjectStream in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I tried to solve the problem for quite a long time and finally decided to take help from experts. I have developed Server-client application using Socket Programming and my client is able to connect to the Server successfully. Now I am trying to send the object over the socket from server based on the request from client, my server is able to catch the request however, response(writeObject(...)) sent by server is not able to reach to the client.
**Server code snippet :**

```
ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(socketNumber);
ArrayList<LoginPassword> logIn = new ArrayList<>();
Socket cSocket = sSocket.accept();
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cSocket.getOutputStream());
outputStream.flush();
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cSocket.getInputStream());
LoginPassword lp1 = new LoginPassword("admin","admin");
logIn.add(lp1);
outputStream.writeObject(logIn);
outputStream.flush();
```

**Clinet code Snippet :**

```
Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),socketNumber);
ArrayList<LoginPassword> myList = new ArrayList<>();
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
outputStream.flush();
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
//Wait untill the data is available
myList = (ArrayList<LoginPassword>) inputStream.readObject();
```

In my case, clients readObject() is never called since it is not able to detect the data sent by Server.Any help please.

Comment: Why do you open an InputStream on the server, since you don't read anything. Same for the client: why do you open an OutputStream, since you don't write anything?

Comment: This is just a code snippet to explain my issue, I am using inputStream and OutputStream in the both, client and server side to send data back and forth while application is running.

Comment: Remove them first, and your code should work fine. Then reintroduce them, but in the right order the client, which reads first, should open the input stream first, read, and then write. The server, which writes first, should open the output stream first, write, and then open the input stream.

Comment: Thanks.However, I tried doing that but still not success.

Comment: Please post your new code and a stack-trace or error message.

Comment: @JBNizet there is nothing 'right' about that ordering. Both sides should open the `ObjectOutputStream` first, to avoid deadlock. Doing that first in one end is actually sufficient, but this way it takes some idiot to change *both* ends to the other order to cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the `ObjectOutputStream` first, preferably at both ends. Otherise you will get a deadlock creating the `ObjectInputStream`.

Alternatively I'd be curious to know what the meaning of the following comment is:

```
// Wait untill the data is available
```

If this indicates a piece of missing code that calls `available()`, just delete it. `readObject()` will block for exactly as long as necessary. There are few correct uses of `available()`, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: OMG that is awesome. I had available() which is waiting for message, when I removed it and directly called readObject() it worked perfectly. Now, after this implementation one more question I have in my mind is, if I do this then it will be blocked until response is not received but in my program sometimes server does not send response if data is not found how can I go ahead from readObject() after given waiting time ?

Comment: Set a read timeout with `Socket.setSoTImeout()`, and catch the `SocketTimeoutException` that results.

Comment: Thank you so much @EJP, I tested it and it works like a charm. Really appreciate your help.